# Encoding error?

Tags: unicode

I am using the following package:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

After adding another paragraph of text into sharelatex as usual, the following error occured:

'*Package inputenc Error: Unicode char -> (U+2192)*

Can someone please tell me what this means and what I have to do to get rid of this error. I can still compile the text and the text looks fine.

Comment: Use `$\to$` instead of →.

Comment: That is the error which says -> I didn't put it?

Comment: wat? I don't get it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Lana thinks you suggested her to replace the `->` in the error message she posted above. I don't get what the question mark is for though ...

Comment: I think the mixup here as to whether the $\to$ or -> can be easily solved by posting a MWE. It is hard to tell what is causing the error when we have just one line of code...

Comment: @HenriMenke Aaah now I see what you mean. I replaced it and now it works thanxx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

U+2192 is a rightarrow so you must have an explicit → in your document.

Note that the default utf8 inputenc settings cover most latin alphabet text characters, but not extended unicode ranges for math or other scripts. these can be added on demand as for example

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\rightarrow}% math mode arrow
```

However you should not get the error that you show on a current latex as U+2192 *is* predefined as a text mode right arrow, inputenc has the definition

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\textrightarrow}
```

Please show a full small document and the full error message.

Comment: I already fixed it, but thanx though! :)